# Sprintf floating a 18,16 float with right padding zeros

Tags: php, printf

I'm trying to get float (18,16) with padding zeros to the right, but this isn't working because it always ends with a 1 instead of a zero. My guess it's because I've specified it wrong but I'm not sure how to do it correct.

Sample:
`12.12234` must become `12.122340000000000` and `1.01` must become `1.01000000000000`.

To achieve this I'm using `sprintf('%18.016f', $fMyFloat);` but this always ends with a 1 instead of a 0. Obviously I'm overseeing something, I just don't know what. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Split on the period, attack with [`str_pad`](http://php.net/str_pad)?

Comment: I've tried that and that works, but I figured it should be possible with sprintf as well. But I couldn't figure out how. It seems when you're floating over 9 digits behind the period it should be treated different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This test code:

```
$data = array(
    12.12234,
    1.01
);
foreach($data as $fMyFloat){
    echo sprintf('%18.016f', $fMyFloat) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

... prints this in my 64-bit computer:

```
12.1223399999999994
1.0100000000000000
```

You are facing the well-known problem of floating point precision. Converting integers from base 10 to base 2 is pretty straightforward (and exact) but base 10 floating point numbers cannot always be represented exactly in base 2. This issue isn't specific to PHP but there's a [warning](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) in the PHP manual:

> Floating point numbers have limited precision. Although it depends on
> the system, PHP typically uses the IEEE 754 double precision format,
> which will give a maximum relative error due to rounding in the order
> of 1.11e-16. Non elementary arithmetic operations may give larger
> errors, and, of course, error propagation must be considered when
> several operations are compounded.
>
> Additionally, rational numbers that are exactly representable as
> floating point numbers in base 10, like 0.1 or 0.7, do not have an
> exact representation as floating point numbers in base 2, which is
> used internally, no matter the size of the mantissa. Hence, they
> cannot be converted into their internal binary counterparts without a
> small loss of precision

Your only chance to achieve such precision is to manipulate numbers as **strings**. PHP bundles two arbitrary precision libraries that can help you when you need to do match with strings: [GNU Multiple Precision](https://www.php.net/gmp) and [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php). Here's a little hack with bcmath:

```
$data = array(
    '12.12234',
    '1.01'
);
bcscale(16);
foreach($data as $fMyFloat){
    echo bcdiv($fMyFloat, 1) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

It this case, though, you can probably use simple string functions:

```
$data = array(
    '12.12234',
    '1.01'
);
foreach($data as $fMyFloat){
    list($a, $b) = explode('.', $fMyFloat);
    echo $a . '.' . str_pad($b, 16, 0) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. Wow. you know this stuff! This goes beyond my knowlegde and I wouldn't have figured this out. Thanks, +1 and accepted. Have a nice day sir. (And you're right, I'm going for the str_pad solution I had before (just like yours)).